# WPF Data Grid not populating with List<List<String>>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I'm using a `List<List<String>>` as my data type to populate a Data Grid from a log file. I've debugged and checked that the data is actually getting inputted properly to my `List<List<String>>` and it appears it is, though when I set my data grid's `ItemsSource` to my `List<List<String>>` my data grid gets populated with the correct number of rows and columns, but is completely empty.

Any ideas why my data isn't going in?

```
string selection = DEFAULT_PATH + @"\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".log";
string line;
//string[] gridValues = new string[8];
List<List<String>> myList = new List<List<String>>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selection))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        List<String> myTempList = new List<String>();
        string[] lines =  new string[8];
        lines = line.Split('\t');
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            myTempList.Add(lines[i]);
        }
        myList.Add(myTempList);
    }
}
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Also, here is the xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="398" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,0,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeStamp" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="EventID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Level" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correlation" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please post the XAML for the DataGrid. That would be more relevant to your question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that it's ok to use an IEnumerable for the ItemsSource member, you are nesting another IEnumerable inside it, representing each row. The DataGrid is not 'smart enough' to go and look for each value within each nested member.

Can you build a class that represents the data in the file, one where each column becomes a public property?

```
public class YourClass {
    public string Column1 {get;set;} // use more meaningful names, of course
    public string Column2 {get;set;}
}
```

Use `List<YourClass>` as the ItemsSource after you assign it's members from the file.

You can quickly initialize public members using the C# shortcut:

`var s = new YourClass() {Column1 = lines[0], Column2 = lines[1], ... };`

Check out [Object initalizers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: Ok, this gives me an error when I make a new `StringArr` like so: `StringArr myStringArr = new StringArr() {lines[0], ... , lines[7]};` and the error is `Cannot initialize type '...StringArr' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: You are creating an inline `string[]`, not a proper initialization. What is `StringArr`? You can inline-initialize with something like `var s = new StringArr() {Column1=lines[0]), Column2=lines[1]...}` etc. I also updated the answer to reflect this tip.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a Class with properties pertaining to each column in your grid. Then in the definition of your column set the DataPropertyName to one of your properties.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string Property1NameHere { get; set; }
    public string Property2NameHere { get; set; }
}

List<YourClass> myList = new List<YourClass>(); 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selection)) 
{ 
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    { 
        ...
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass() { ... };
        myList.Add(yourClass);  
    }
}

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding to the dataGrid ItemSource property is enumerating the outer `List<T>` which each element contained is a `List<String>`.  If you want to bind to a `List<List<String>>` then you are going to have some problems.  The following should give you a datagrid that has the Count and Capacity properties of the outer list:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

With the code behind (not a fan of code behind, but for this quick example):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<List<String>> nestedList = new List<List<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        List<String> innerListElement = new List<string>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            innerListElement.Add(String.Format("{0} - Element {1}", i, x));
        }
        nestedList.Add(innerListElement);
    }
    myGrid.ItemsSource = nestedList;
}
```

There isn't a clean way to do the data binding to handle in this example since there isn't a good reference name for each of the inner `List<T>` elements.

You may consider binding to a `List<KeyValuePair<String, List<String>>` or some combination that gives you an inner reference so the binding path has something to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeStamp" Binding="{Binding [0]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Process" Binding="{Binding [1]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="TID" Binding="{Binding [2]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" Binding="{Binding [3]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding [4]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="EventID" Binding="{Binding [5]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Level" Binding="{Binding [6]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding [7]}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Correlation" Binding="{Binding [8]}" />
```

Not 100% sure, but I believe this will give you what you are looking for.